# How to combine multiple datasets into one dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tfrecord, tf.keras, eager-execution

Suppose I have 3 tfrecord files, namely `neg.tfrecord`, `pos1.tfrecord`, `pos2.tfrecord`.

I use

```
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(tfrecord_file)
```

this code creates 3 Dataset objects.

My batch size is 400, including 200 neg data, 100 pos1 data, and 100 pos2 data. How can I get the desired dataset?

I will use this dataset object in keras.fit() (Eager Execution).

My tensorflow's version is 1.13.1.

Before, I tried to get the iterator for each dataset, and then manually concat after getting the data, but it was inefficient and the GPU utilization was not high.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `interleave`

```
filenames = [tfrecord_file1, tfrecord_file2]
dataset = (Dataset.from_tensor_slices(filenames).interleave(lambda x:TFRecordDataset(x)
dataset = dataset.map(parse_fn)
...
```

Or you can even try parallel interleave. See https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/TFRecordDataset#interleave
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/parallel_interleave

Comment: yes, it work! But I found that interleave can only read 3 tfrecord files on average. If my current batch size is 400, I need to take 200 samples from neg, 100 samples for pos1, and 100 samples for pos2. How can i do?

Comment: You can do this in your parse function. Or maybe flat_map will suite you https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#flat_map 
Or maybe it's better to create another question with more specifics and include code that you've tried

Answer (score -1):

This worked for a project I am currently executing on Kaggle.
I read in 5 datasets for different years and used the following code to merge them.
Blessings- john-Eric

frames=[df,df1,df2,df3,df4]

data = pd.concat(frames)

data

Comment: Hi, the original poster is not asking combining multiple `pandas.dataframe`.