# How to combine multiple tfrecord datasets into one dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tfrecord

**Suppose I have 3 tfrecord files, namely `neg.tfrecord`, `pos1.tfrecord`, `pos2.tfrecord`.**

**My batch size is 500, including 300 neg data, 100 pos1 data, and 100 pos2 data. How can I get the desired TFRecordDataset?**

I will use this TFRecordDataset object in keras.fit() (Eager Execution).

My tensorflow's version is 1.13.1. I find the API in [tf.data.Dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset), such as `interleave`, `concatenate`, `zip`, but it seems that I can't solve my problem.

Before, I tried to get the iterator for each dataset, and then manually concat after getting the data, but it was inefficient and the GPU utilization was not high.

And in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55154836/how-to-combine-multiple-datasets-into-one-dataset/55155937?noredirect=1#comment97059416_55155937), I use `interleave` below:

```py
tfrecord_files = ['neg.tfrecord', 'pos1.tfrecord', 'pos2.tfrecord']
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tfrecord_files)
def _parse(x):
    x = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(x)
    return x
dataset = dataset.interleave(_parse, cycle_length=4, block_length=1)
dataset = dataset.apply(tf.data.experimental.map_and_batch(_parse_image_function, 500))
```

and I got this batch:

```
neg pos1 pos2 neg pos1 pos2 ...............
```

But what I want is this:

```
neg neg neg pos1 pos2 neg neg neg pos1 pos2 .................
```

What I should do?

Looking forward to answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced something like what you said using string data:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def string_data(s):
    return tf.sparse.to_dense(tf.strings.split([s]), default_value='')[0]

data = [' '.join(['neg'] * 30), ' '.join(['pos1'] * 10), ' '.join(['pos2'] * 10)]
step_sizes = tf.constant([3, 1, 1], dtype=tf.int64)
ds = (tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data, step_sizes))
      .interleave(lambda d, s: (tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(string_data(d))
                                .batch(s)),
                  cycle_length=len(data))
      .flat_map(tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices))
iter = ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    while True:
        try:
            print(sess.run(iter).decode(), end=', ')
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError: break
    print()
```

Output:

```
neg, neg, neg, pos1, pos2, neg, neg, neg, pos1, pos2, neg, neg, neg, pos1, pos2, neg, neg, neg, pos1, pos2, neg, neg, neg, pos1, pos2, neg, neg, neg, pos1, pos2, neg, neg, neg, pos1, pos2, neg, neg, neg, pos1, pos2, neg, neg, neg, pos1, pos2, neg, neg, neg, pos1, pos2,
```

In the real use case you would replace `data` with the list of file names and `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(string_data(d))` with `tf.data.TFRecordDataset(d)`, but otherwise it should work similarly.

EDIT: I just realised that you actually wanted a batch of all elements ordered in that way, not just one element at a time, so I suppose you would have to add another `batch` call at the end.